# How do I produce a PDF from imagemagick with Fast Web View enabled?

Tags: windows, browser, pdf, imagemagick, preview

I collate a bunch of images into a single PDF using ImageMagick. While this works properly, when I open the PDF on the browser and go to properties, it's showing that Fast Web View is not enabled for the file which makes it wait until the whole thing is loaded before showing anything.

Is it possible to have ImageMagick do this?

Comment: `pdfopt input.pdf output.pdf` should resolve the issue

Comment: It does not seem to be available on Windows

Comment: You should install ghostscript and you will find it as `pdfopt.bat`.

Comment: I have ghostscript 10.0.0 installed and I did a system-wide search for pdfopt.bat and I couldn't find it

Comment: Use `gs`  with `-dFastWebView`

Comment: Okay I tried `gs -dFastWebView input.pdf output.pdf` and then it complained that `Error: /undefinedfilename in (output.pdf)`

Comment: Okay I found the proper syntax, `gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFastWebView -f input.pdf` which works, thanks!

Comment: Do you see any difference in loading speed?

Comment: @MaxWyss Opening in the browser, the first page shows up while the rest of the file is still loading. With it off, I have to wait until the whole file is loaded first before I see anything at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Ghostscript to convert the PDF file to new with Fast Web View option. For this you need to use option `-dFastWebView`.

And you found the rest :)

```
gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFastWebView -f input.pdf
```